# node prints undefined after console.log() with a javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am test JavaScript dictionary on node console as follows

```
$ node
> var dict = {};
undefined
> dict["t"] = "table";
'table'
> console.log(dict);
{ t: 'table' }
undefined
> dict["f"] = "field";
'field'
> console.log(dict);
{ t: 'table', f: 'field' }
undefined
> console.log(dict.t);
table
undefined
> console.log(dict.f);
field
undefined
> console.log(dict['f']);
field
undefined
> var str = "f";
undefined
> console.log(dict[str]);
field
undefined
```

The dictionary works fine but what are those "undefined" mean? What did I miss here?

Thanks,

Comment: The console prints out the value of the last expression evaluated. `console.log()` returns `undefined`, and similarly a `var` declaration results in `undefined`.

Comment: why var declaration would return undefined?

Comment: I guess that since it's a statement and not specifically an *expression* statement, the value is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comment should really have been an answer:

> The console prints out the value of the last expression evaluated. console.log() returns undefined, and similarly a var declaration results in undefined. – Pointy

Comment: So the undefined does not indicate any error and I do not have to try and get rid of the "undefined"?

Comment: @Shawn right - nothing's wrong with your code. It's just the console doing its thing.